# python json config variable key replacement in multiple levels of hierarchy

Tags: python, json, config

i plan to use json for config file and currently i have a config like this

```
{
  "settings": {
    "general": "root",
    "folder": "folder_test"
  },
  "TEST1": {
    "dataone": "xyz",
    "testing": {
      "a": "$general/$folder/test.png",
      "b": "$general/$folder/test.png"
    },
    "SOMELIST": [
      "$general/$folder/test.png",
      "$general/$folder/test.png"
    ]
  },
  "TEST2": {
    "dataone": "xyz",
    "testing": {
      "a": "$general/$folder/test.png",
      "b": "$general/$folder/test.png"
    },
    "something": {
        "test_data": {
          tester: {
            "abc": "$general/$folder/test.png",
            "zxv": "$general/$folder/test.png"
          }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

my purpose is to have the settings section fill with static path such as root and folder name etc and have the rest of the other parts of config through out the entire config hierarchy to use the settings as a variable. This is for path and folder purpose which i won't have any issue in maintaining later if the root or new folder change/added.

i wanted to have the config to be able to use all the settings variable throughout any levels of hierarchy later even with newly added levels in the future.

so far i only able to loop one level but not sure how to access multiple levels as general.

```
for k, v in config.items():
    for key in config.keys():
        if key in v:
            config[k] = v.replace("$" + key, config[key])
```

found this in another topic in stackoverflow here but this is only one level. I am not sure how to build a general one that can include multiple of levels here.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of replacing the variables for each item individually, have you considered just replacing the variables before parsing it as JSON? That's way less memory/computationally expensive, and it should be much easier.

```
config = ""
with open("config.json") as f:
    config = f.read().replace("$variable", "stackoverflow")

parsed_config = your_parser(config)
```

Edit: Wrote a recursive replace function. I hope you can read it & learn from it.

```
import json

call_counter = 0

def replace_string(value: str, template_vars: {}) -> object:
    """
    Replaces template strings in value, by the values in template_vars. 
    """
    for template, newValue in template_vars.items():
        value = value.replace("${}".format(template), newValue)

    return value


def replace_recursive(json_obj: object, template_vars: {}) -> {}:
    """
    Recursively unpacks and replaces items in a multi-dimensional dict/list/item json object.
    """
    # For each item at this level 
    for key, value in json_obj.items():
        # If the value is a string, replace it
        if isinstance(value, str):
            json_obj[key] = replace_string(value, template_vars)        

        # If the item is a list, we need to do something for each value
        elif isinstance(value, list):
            # Enumate unpacks an index with each value
            for index, item in enumerate(value):
                # If it's a string, we can replace it 
                if isinstance(item, str):
                    value[index] = replace_string(item, template_vars)
                # If it's not, we need to do more work. 
                else:
                    value[index] = replace_recursive(item, template_vars)

        # If it's a dict, use this function again to unpack/replace the values
        else:
            json_obj[key] = replace_recursive(value, template_vars)

    return json_obj

if __name__ == "__main__":

    template_vars = {}

    # Read our file
    with open("example.json") as f:
        json = json.load(f)

    # Read our settings
    template_vars = json['settings']

    # Drop our settings block (don't if you don't want to)
    json.pop('settings')

    json = replace_recursive(json, template_vars)
    print(json)
```

This uses quite a few function calls. Not a problem for this config, but it may be for another.

Comment: possible for this way to be more generic instead of the need to maintain when there is a new setting path added? is kinda like semi in this case.